# problem with comparing date in Ruby (findbySql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

WHERE

```
l.created_at > #{params[:daysAgo].to_i.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}
```

is working correctly but

WHERE

```
l.created_at > '#{params[:daysAgo].to_i.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00')}'
```

is not returning any rows... can anyone help.. but for date comparison we should use quotes right..??

Comment: You shouldn't use string interpolation in building SQL queries. In this case there's no risk of SQL injection, but it's better to think like there is always a risk.

Comment: using the queries without quote is valid??

Comment: try to use conditions in following way
:conditions => ['created_at < ?', params[:daysAgo].to_i.days.ago]
in this case rails will handle it

Comment: (SELECT CONCAT(pa.city, ', ', pa.state) AS city_state, pa.city, pa.state, COUNT(l.id) AS unassigned_leads FROM leads l LEFT JOIN prospects p ON p.id = l.prospect_id LEFT JOIN addresses pa ON p.id = pa.addressable_id AND pa.addressable_type = 'Prospect'
WHERE
l.created_at > #{params[:daysAgo].to_i.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_s}

Comment: i cannot use conditions here...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert time to database one by `to_s(:db)`

For example,

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

I found that database time is better use `Time.zone` in Rails

```
Time.zone.now.to_s(:db)
```